# Cannot drag and drop items from toolbox in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

The problem that I cannot drag and drop items from toolbox in Visual Studio in C# project .

When I am trying to drag from the toolbox, this error shows up:

[image]

And when I am trying to move any component inside the Design Form with the mouse, it's not moved, it only works if moved by pressing arrow keys:

[image]

And when I open the project this error shows up:

[image]

I tried

1. Reset toolbox
2. Repair toolbox
3. Delete the file `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml`
4. Uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall it

Answer (score 1):

These two errors are not caused by the same issue.

**1. Regarding "the operation could not be completed.**

The system cannot find the file specified", it is because Visual Studio cannot correctly select the .NET Framework.

You can use the Visual Studio installation tool to uninstall the .net framework you are using and then reinstall it.

If it still doesn't work, please try to cd to the directory of devenv.exe from the command line. For example, my devenv.exe is located in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE
```

I just type cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE

Then execute the command

```
Devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

Wait for vs to open and close

```
Devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

Wait for vs to open and close

However, some personal settings will be lost in this way, such as External Tools in customized tools, so be sure to back them up.

**2. For "The 'ORMDataModelPackage' package did not load correctly".**

It's because the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Sdk.Shell.15.0 assembly is missing. Usually after closing and opening Visual Studio this error will not appear again. If it doesn't work, please run the Visual Studio installer and install the DSL-Tools component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried that but the error stills

Comment: What version of the DevExpress suite do you have installed? Are you using a community/express or pro version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Iam using visual studio ultimate 2012 and visual studio pro 2017